# Tokenizing strings in a "String RDD" returning another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I have a Spark RDD of individual string values, where each string is formed out of words separated by `|` symbols.

This RDD was generated by a SparkSQL query, NOT by a `.textFile(...)` load operation.

I can't (unless I'm miss-understanding something fundamental) use a `.flatMap(_.split("|"))` operation as this flattens each string to individual characters before applying the `.split()`.

However, I do need to do something like a `.flatMap()` in that I need a 1 to many mapping. As my data set is potentially very large I need this operation to parallelize, hence the use of RDDs and related operations.

Interestingly when processing strings from RDDs loaded using `.textFile(...)`, then the `.flatMap(...)` operation does exactly what I want! So I'm guessing that there must be a way...

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: >>as this flattens each string to individual characters before applying the .split() Why do you think so?

Comment: Sorry, this was wrong! I allowed myself to get confused. This was caused by me splitting on the `|` symbol and I now realise this will be interpreted as a REGEX or operation. So I was effectively splitting on `""` which of course ends up giving me individual characters!!  So, if I use `"""\|"""` instead everything works as expected. Sorry, and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am not sure I understand the problem, but I will try to help.

In `.flatMap(_.split("|"))` the split breaks the words of each line, and at the end it is flattened. If you don't need to flatten the result, perhaps you can use `.map(_.split("|"))`.

Comment: On an RDD generated by a .textFile() load the .flatMap() operation does split strings into words when used with an appropriate .split(). However, I think these are somehow special, as on other string RDDs the .flatmap() appears to first flatten the string to characters and then applies the provided function. Using .map() as you suggested to map the compound strings to arrays of tokens. I was hoping to produce a RDD of just the tokens, not arrays of them.

Comment: `flatMap` should work in your case. Try to flatten at the end of the computation using this: `x.flatMap(y => y)`. What's the result?

Comment: I had already tried that, `.flatMap(y => y)` flattens each string to its constituent characters However, I have managed to achieve my end result by using `.mapPartions()`. Here I used the provided iterator to loop over the strings in the RDD and then tokenized each one into a buffer. I the returned the buffer's iterator, i.e. DIY `flatMap()`...

Comment: After a good sleep I realised a very silly mistake which explains the behaviour I was seeing. See my comment attached to the original question for an explanation. Thanks for helping! I wonder if anyone else has been caught out by this! The `.flatMap()` method works perfectly and of course always did!